# Button doesn 't show when dragged into layout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

When i try to add a button to my layout i can't edit it or see it when i run the application. I think the map Fragment is overlapping the button but i'm not sure.
Anyone know the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Roan Kers
layout:
[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXypu.png)
xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/toolbar" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace these two:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

I just changed the TextView height to `wrap_content` and added layout_weight of 1 to the fragment.

Comment: I see what you mean. While this is an option, I want the button to be placed on top of the map. Is this even possible?

Comment: Not with a Linear Layout. you need to take the Button out of the Linear Layout and constraint it to the bottom of the screen so that it covers the bottom of the map. if you want I can update my answer and show you that?

Answer (score 0):

With `LinearLayout` it's not possible for one view to overlap another view.

`LinearLayout` is vertical in your case, so views are one below another. Its height set to `match_parent` so it can't be bigger than screen height.

Let's see next:

- `<fragment>` height set for `match_parent` too. So this parent takes full layout height and views which are below shrank into zero height. You need to decrease its height, use `wrap_content` or fixed height in `dp`.
- `<TextView>` height set for `match_parent`. Everything is the same as for fragment view. Decrease its height.
- `<Button>` is just below these views and visible only if there's a place in layout for it.

Comment: I see what you mean. While this is an option, I want the button to be placed on top of the map. Is this even possible?

Comment: Of course. You should look at other layout options like `ConstraintLayout` or `RelativeLayout`. These layouts suppose views can overlap each other. `ConstraintLayout` is basically a layout which can be considered as default for any complex layout.